# F# syntactic sugar

Tags: syntax, f#

F# clearly contains a lot of things that are syntactic sugar, and as I try to learn it--without the aid of a book--I am overwhelmed by the sheer variety of syntax. Is there a simpler "core" language hidden behind all that syntactic sugar? Is there a cheat sheet list of the syntactic sugars and how they map to the core language?

And hey, is there a reason F# requires a different "assignment" operator for function definitions than for lambdas, or was it a random decision? e.g. "let inc x = x+1" vs "fun x -> x+1"

Comment: if you have #Light on, turn it off.

Comment: Since all the examples I see have #light on, I wouldn't have a clue how to write F# code without it.

Comment: The F# spec goes over what the #light syntax does (section 15, IIRC). In general, you'll be adding a lot of "in" everywhere. I don't think it's helpful to turn it off (for learning), as the #light syntax is pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 6):

A great deal of F# syntax comes from OCaml - many OCaml programs will compile and run in F# with no changes.

Good starter links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/fsharp/default.aspx

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming

http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!887.entry?_c=BlogPart

Answer (score 4):

Along with Brian's links, I'd like to pass along links to my own blog series, [Why I Love F#](http://diditwith.net/CategoryView,category,Why%2BI%2BLove%2BF%23.aspx), which covers some of the basics.

With regard to your second question, "let inc x = x+1" vs "fun x -> x+1" are two ways of expressing a function, but only the first one uses the assignment operator. In fact,

```
let inc x = x + 1
```

Is equivalent to:

```
let inc = (fun x -> x + 1)
```

The first is shorthand for the second, but the second might illuminate how all functions in F# are really lambdas bound to names.

Answer (score 3):

F#, barring .NET interop, seems quite simpler than, say C#. (Not really picking on it in particular, but since it's another popular .NET language...)

Take F# functions, for instance:

- There's no magic "void" type-thats-not-really-a-type

  - Hence everything is an expression
- All functions are unary
- Functions are first class type

Right there you have a function system that's vastly easier than, say, C#, where void creates a special case, and there's no generalization possible over all functions.

As to your specific question, with "let f x = x" versus "let f = fun x -> x", that's probably an inherited trait from ML. (I don't see any particular reason why it couldn't be "let f = fun x = x", except that perhaps it'd be more confusing and perhaps make the grammar more complex?. (Personally I'd prefer "let f = \x.x".)) Anyways, while in most cases they are equivalent, sometimes you must define a syntactic function instead of a function value.

.NET interop can, unfortunately, make things a bit more complicated, although probably not more or much more than other .NET languages.

Comment: 'no magic "void" type-thats-not-really-a-type' other than unit of course.

Comment: Yeah, just what I was thinking. Or Haskell's (). Although I think it was ill-advised that C#/C/C++/Java doesn't have "define function" and "define variable" keywords, I don't think C# syntax is nearly as bad as C++, the language it was largely based on.

Comment: Unit has a value, (). No magic there:

> id ();;
val it : unit = ()

How do you pass a value of void? How can you, say, in C#, declare a delegate that encompasses any function? You can't. You're stuck with separate codepaths for void (Action) versus nonvoid (Func).

Comment: "any function"? I don't know of a statically typed language that lets you call "any function" without regard for its argument types. And if you can't convert Func<int,int> to Action<int> for example, that's a limitation of the .NET Framework itself (bad variance support) and not of the C# language.

Comment: Vote for covariant return types at https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=90909 ...

Comment: I didn't say call, I said generalize. You can't do Func<void, int> in C#, so you often end up having a split set of functions to do any higher order function work.

Answer (score 2):

Only one of the two expressions you mentioned uses an assignment operator.

This defines a function bound to the identifier "inc" which takes a single argument of type int and returns the argument +1.

```
let inc x = x + 1;
```

This on the other hand, is an expression which represents a lambda.  It is bound to no identifier cannot exist solely by itself.  It must be part of a larger expression.

```
fun x -> x + 1
```

Comment: I know what functions are and I know what a lambda is.

Comment: @Qwertie, then you should state your question in a clearer fashion

Comment: I think it's pretty clear I didn't ask WHAT a function or WHAT a lambda is. Rather it was a question about the syntax.

Comment: @Qwertie, i disagree.  I find your last sentence ambigous and chose to give an answer for one interpretation.

Comment: Okay, sorry, it's just that I'm a newbie. I don't know the correct terminology. The assignment operators I was referring to are "=" in the case of "let" and "->" in the case of "fun".

Comment: @Qwertie, not an issue. I'm an F# newbie as well (hint trust whatever Brian says).  I'm not sure if -> actually classifies as assignment in F# though because as assignment requires LHS identifier.  A lambda by definition has no identifier.  Brian would know for sure

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a cheat sheet for F#, this is the one that I use on a regular basis.

[fsharpcheatsheet.pdf](http://www.scribd.com/doc/37687368/fsharpcheatsheet)

It doesn't cover everything, things like Units of Measure or quotations, and doesn't talk about the various libraries, but it does cover a lot of the syntax.

Comment: Updated the link to a copy stored on scribd.  The cheat sheet wasn't updated, so it is out of date.  But it does have some of the basis syntax.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.samskivert.com/code/fsharp/fsharp-cheat-sheet.pdf

It's a pretty comprehensive cheat sheet that has helped me out a lot with learning F#

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you can apply directly a lambda in an expression.

```
let i = (fun x -> x + 1)0  //i equal 1
```